# Take a reference to a Perl operator

Tags: perl, reference

In Perl, is it possible to take a sub reference to an operator (e.g. `eq` or `gt`)? Or is it not possible because they are not subs? I'd like to avoid redefining operators as subs where a comparison function is required.

I'm applying a checking function to config values, where the checker depends on the config key. One such checker is "compare to another key's value". The compare function can be defined via anonymous sub, or a named sub can be implement for each comparison type, but I think it's nicer to be able to say `compare_to("OTHER_KEY", \&eq)`.

EDIT: since one commentator wanted context and someone else voted to close as "too broad", I'll be *absolutely clear* that the question is not "how to write a config checker". This is only about taking references to operators: is it possible or not, what caveats apply?

Comment: How is the comparison function going to be used?

Comment: Should I take that to mean "no, but maybe you can solve it some other way"? I'm interested in the answer for its own sake as well. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparisons like `eq` and `gt` fall under a special category of the CORE functions where you can't create references to them.  This is detailed in the documentation here http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html

So it looks like you can't do what you want to.  I think your options include:

- Use anonymous subs or named subs to wrap the comparator you want to use
- Passing in the string `'eq'` and doing an `if` in `compare_to` and calling your comparator there.
- You could do what some other languages do and make the second argument 1, 0, or -1 and take that to stand for `gt`, `eq`, `lt`, then if the value is a coderef, call that.
- There might be a psuedo-magic way to approach this using `AUTOLOAD` if you are interested in going down that route.

**Update:**

Example of `AUTOLOAD` magic:

```
use feature qw( say );

my %bin_ops = map { $_ => 1 } qw( eq ne gt lt );
sub AUTOLOAD {
    $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://;
    die "..." if !$bin_ops{$AUTOLOAD};
    return eval "\$_[0] $AUTOLOAD \$_[1]";
}

sub compare_to {
    my ($sub, $a, $b) = @_;
    return $sub->($a, $b);
}

say compare_to(\&eq, 1, 1) ? "yep" : "nope";
say compare_to(\&eq, 1, 0) ? "yep" : "nope";
say compare_to(\&gt, 1, 0) ? "yep" : "nope";
say compare_to(\&lt, 1, 0) ? "yep" : "nope";
```

Running it:

```
> perl tmp/test_coreref.pl
yep
nope
yep
nope
```

There might be a way to do that without using eval, but I'm not going to pursue this further for the time being.

Comment: I would be interested in any magical approach for the sake of intellectual curiosity but am very unlikely to actually use it (would be substantial less clear than just wrapping the operator).

Comment: Using `for (qw( eq ne gt lt )) { eval "sub $_ { \$_[0] $_ \$_[1] }" }` is way faster that that nasty and illegal use of AUTOLOAD!

Comment: Re "*There might be a way to do that without using eval*", You can obfuscate the `eval` using `require`, `do` and `s///ee`, but you'd still be calling `eval`, a necessary step in generating code.

Comment: @ikegami re: `nasty and illegal use of AUTOLOAD` - I assume this is your opinion?  I also read that with a joking tone, but it's hard to tell from just text.  I find `AUTOLOAD` *weird* and a obfuscating, but also can be really cool.  Also, yes, your example would be faster.

Comment: It's not so nasty now that I added `die "..." if !$bin_ops{$AUTOLOAD};`. Now it's just nasty in terms of speed. (The OP is balking at calling a simple sub, so instead you posted a solution that involves calling a very complex sub, plus `eval`, plus the body of the OP was trying to avoid in the first place! /// As for illegal, AUTOLOAD is for methods, but you're using it for a non-method.

Comment: I apparently remember incorrectly for the illegal bit. It clearly show it used for sub calls in the docs.

Comment: I had assumed the reason he didn't want to create more subs to handle all the different comparators he might possibly want to use was that he didn't want to create the extra code, not for performance reasons.  I agree that checking a list of approved options is generally a good idea.  Keep in mind that example was only added because OP was interested in learning more about **black magic** perl.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a string is done using `"abc"`.

Creating an operator is done using `sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] }` or like `eval('$_[0] eq $_[1]')`.

These don't duplicate the operator; they create it.

In the comments, you keep insisting your question asks if it's possible to get a reference to an operator without creating it ("wrapping" it in code) first. Obviously, the answer is no.

---

The question, on the other hand, asks if it's possible to get a reference to an operator, or rather, to `eq` specifically.

It is possible to take a reference to some operators using `\&CORE::op_name`<sup>[1]</sup>, but not `eq`. The automatic generation of a sub using that syntax is only supported for operators whose syntax can be approximated by a sub with a prototype<sup>[2]</sup>.

Of course, you could easily create a callable instance of the operator yourself instead of having Perl create it for you:

```
my $eq = sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] };

compare("OTHER_KEY", $eq)
```

or

```
sub eq { $_[0] eq $_[1] }

compare("OTHER_KEY", \&eq)
```

If you want to avoid code duplication (of having a bunch of similar sub declarations), you can use a `eval`.

```
eval("sub $_ { \$_[0] $_ \$_[1] }")
   for qw( eq ne gt lt );

compare("OTHER_KEY", \&eq)
```

You could simply use the following, but that would be incredibly wasteful and dangerous:

```
sub compare {
   ref($_[1])
      ? $_[1]->($val, $_[0])
      : eval("\$val $_[1] \$_[0]")
}

compare("OTHER_KEY", "eq")`
```

If you don't want to involve any subs, the only alternative is:

```
sub compare {
   ref($_[1]) ? $_[1]->($val, $_[0]) :
   $_[1] eq "eq" ? $val eq $_[0] :
   $_[1] eq "ne" ? $val ne $_[0] :
   $_[1] eq "lt" ? $val lt $_[0] :
   $_[1] eq "gt" ? $val gt $_[0] :
   die "Bad argument";
}
```

---

1. Since 5.16.
2. Only those for which `prototype("CORE::op_name")` returns a defined value.  This is true for some named list operators (e.g. `length`) and some named unary operators (e.g. `time`), but it isn't for any named binary operators (e.g. `eq`).

Comment: I shouldn't have restricted my "avoid redefining" requirement to anonymous subs - obviously named works just as well. This is exactly what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Out of interest in whether it is possible and because – IMO – duplication is distracting when reading code (and especially inelegant for built-in functionality).

Comment: As I said in the question, I suspected it would not be possible because they are not subs. So the answer is simply "no".

Comment: `say` actually does not have such a sub according to the `CORE` documentation. There's more subtlety too because some of them can have references created but not be called via those references, and `eq` and friends are actually keywords like `while`. All of this information would have been really nice in an answer, leaving aside personal style preferences :(

Comment: I didn't say that you suggested anything. You seem to be under the impression that my question was something different than what I intended: can I create a reference to an operator to avoid wrapping it in a sub (explicitly mentioning `eq`). My dislike for wrapping is not the question; it's not a terrible choice but *my* preference is not to do it if possible. You repeated several times how obvious it is that you can't do this - that *is* the question! I suspected as much and stated so in the question. There is also more subtlety, which is interesting. I don't know how to be clearer than that.

Comment: I don't know why you need to keep repeating that when it has already been acknowledged. Thanks for your edits; your answer is now much more informative.

Comment: I don't see the point in continuing in circles and being (somewhat aggressively) accused of things, so I won't post further here if you want to have that level of conversation. My understanding from the documentation is that some operators can have references taken (since 5.16), some cannot, and some can but cannot be called via those references. The common binary comparison operators fall into the second category, so it is not possible to achieve what I asked for those. Which part specifically of my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: I added the answer to the question you asked in the comments to my answer.

Comment: Re "*some operators can have references taken (since 5.16), some cannot*", No, you can do it for any operator (as I showed). You just can't use the `\&CORE::syntax` for some of them. /// Re "*some can but cannot be called via those references*", That doesn't make any sense.